# Infinite loop in a simple React Component

Tags: function, if-statement, count, numbers

[image: Error: Too many re-renders.]

They gave us this simple exercise but I'm stuck at this point. With the IF function I am looking when the counter reaches 0 it does not count negative numbers. I got this error:

Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an **infinite loop**. why is this happening?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi, never give code as Image!

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the issue, just use only an IF with the following parameters:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  if (count < 0) {
    setCount(0);
  }
```

Problem solved